# Помогите сделать код читабельным

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

У меня есть такой код

```
if (position!=1&&position!=2){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}

if (position==1){
    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Акции временно не работают", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
if (position==2){
    if (strTotalPrice<500) Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Минимальная сумма заказа 500 руб.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

Подскажите как можно сделать данный код более читабельным. А то код новичка будто)).

Если есть другой сайт для подобных вещей. То дайте плиз ссылку.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
switch(position)
{
    case 1:
       Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Акции временно не работают", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
    case 2:
       if (strTotalPrice<500) Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Минимальная сумма заказа 500 руб.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       else viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
    break;
    default:
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
    break;
}
drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Comment: Спасибо Юрий. Я код чуток изменил. Можете измененный код через свитч еще раз?

Comment: @xTIGRx, так просто же копирнуть и всё... А вообще менять ТЗ после его исполнения - плохо. Вы ж, вроде, фрилансер, а таким занимаетесь(

Comment: Все спасибо)). Копирнуть это дело школьников, а я хочу разобраться в этом. Благодаря вашему коду и чуток погулив в инете. Я понял как работает default. Спасибо большое))

Answer (score 5):

Для начала, чтобы повысить читабельность кода, советую обратиться к документу

[Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

В конвенции есть правила которых стоит придерживаться при написании Java библиотек, правила стиля оформления кода, правила языка Java и т.д.
Этих правил стоит придерживаться, чтобы ваш код был лаконичен, понятен и, самое главное, "привычен" всем программистам. 
Во многих компаниях есть свои соглашения по написанию кода, но это уже другая история.

Есть множество переводов Java Code Conventions на русский, но лучше, по возможности, все-таки прочитать в оригинале. Тем более сделать это надо всего лишь один раз.

Конкретно в вашем примере, следующие нарушения конвенции:

- операторы необходимо отделять пробелами

  ```
  if (position != 1 && position != 2) {
  ```
- между параметрами так же необходим пробел

  ```
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
  ```
- В Java принято всегда использовать фигурные скобки, даже для "однострочных" условий, каждая строка с новой строчки

  ```
      if (strTotalPrice < 500) {
          Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Минимальная сумма заказа 500 руб.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
          viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
      }
  ```

Я не обращаю внимания на структуру кода (ввести взаимоисключающие if...else, либо перейти на switch...case), я сделал пост о нарушении конвенции Java для написания кода, надеюсь это будет полезно

Comment: Ага, спасибо...

Answer (score 4):

Использовать `switch` и избавиться от дублирования кода:

```
switch (position) {
    case 1:
        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Акции временно не работают", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 2:
        if (strTotalPrice<500) {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Минимальная сумма заказа 500 руб.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        /* falls through */
    default:
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
}

drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Вроде [ideone](//ideone.com/3j0MRM) не показывает ошибок кроме несуществующих классов.

PS: А если уж хочется использовать взаимоисключающие `if`, то имеет смысл ставить `else`.